# using apt-clone on fresh ubuntu 16.04 installs php 7.0

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php7

im trying to clone my server setup without websites.  I am doing this so others can use the same server setup as mine.

My setup does not include apache
my setup does not include php7.0

however when installing the clone to a fresh ubuntu 16.04 it installs apache and php7.0 non of which are included in my clone.

it totally ignores the php7.1 and all dependence from the clone

it seems that ubuntu 16.04 overides the install and chooses to install apache and php7.0.

I have checked the install files over and there is not mention of apache or php7.0

here is a copy of the install https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3zpwveb4y761hg/foo.apt-clone.tar.gz

hope someone can help.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `apt-clone` only clones the package names, not the actual repositories defined in the system. Therefore you need to check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` content and copy that also to the destination system.

Another issue could be a mismatch between source and destination system OS versions.

Comment: thank you so much. this really helped and stops the install of php7 however it still install apache and this messes with the configuration of nginx.  I dont know why its still installing apache its annoying the hell out of me though.  I have a feeling that the original server install did in fact install apache and then i uninstalled it. you dont know of any other method to clone my server setup do you,  I have a feeling that apt-clone is not going to do what I want it to.

Comment: My approach is to use a configuration management system like Puppet or Ansible, where you first create a configuration template for your server and then use that to install the servers. However, this cannot be used to clone existing systems.

Comment: thanks for your reply, im now rebuilding another test server from scratch making sure not to install apache.  so good so far.  im hoping that i can then clone the system.  I do remember removing apache on the original stack it must be tied in to the repos somewhere.  I tried to plus your answer but I need 15 rank :(   Ill try answer some questions later on then come back and vote up.  Thanks again @Tero Kilkanen